# jquery How do I hide a single html object being clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing jquery tutorial on W3Schools. I ask out of curiosity and learning, that's all. No business applications.

I want to click an HTML element and hide it using one function only.

I click on (h1,h2,p), but it seems that I need to pass the function the tag itself to hide it when using $(this).

I've tried

```
$(*).click(function(){
```

but this hides everything. My code is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $([the HTML object I'm clicking on now]).click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

If you click on me, I will disappear.

### Click me away!

Click me too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference to the objects you want to manipulate on, then use `this` keyword, to apply the function on a specified (clicked) element.

```js
$('.box, input, .btn').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
<input class='input'>
<button class='btn'>click</button>
```